# Does SharePoint user profile service distinguish blocked users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, active-directory

I added an external app to show an Org chart inside our sharepoint modern page, now the app will read the users' info and their managers from the sharepoint user profile service. when i first load the Org chart i find that some leavers are showing, which is something we do not want to have, so i apply the following filtering inside the Org chart external app:-

> SPS-HideFromAddressLists == "No" || SPS-HideFromAddressLists ==
>   "False"

and a lot of leavers will no more show which is great. but still we  have couple of users who are blocked, as follow:-

[image]

but still been shown inside the Org chart. so my question is which property inside the sharepoint user profile service indicates if the user is Blocked or not? so i can add additional filtering to the Org chart app to exclude blocked users.

Here is the list of properties which the app provides to filter users (i am already using the `SPS-HideFromAddressLists` as shown above which worked for some leavers ):-

```
AboutMe (About me)
AccountName (Account name)
ADGuid (Active Directory Id)
SPS-Responsibility (Ask Me About)
Assistant (Assistant)
SPS-Birthday (Birthday)
SPS-ClaimProviderID (Claim Provider Identifier)
SPS-ClaimProviderType (Claim Provider Type)
SPS-ClaimID (Claim User Identifier)
SPS-DataSource (Data source)
DelveFlags (DelveFlags)
Department (Department)
SPS-DisplayOrder (Display Order)
SPS-DistinguishedName (Distinguished Name)
SPS-DontSuggestList (Don’t Suggest List)
SPS-Dotted-line (Dotted-line Manager)
SPS-EmailOptin (Email Notifications)
Fax (Fax)
FirstName (First name)
SPS-HireDate (Hire date)
HomePhone (Home phone)
UserProfile_GUID (Id)
SPS-Interests (Interests)
SPS-JobTitle (Job Title)
SPS-LastColleagueAdded (Last Colleague Added)
SPS-LastKeywordAdded (Last Keyword Added)
LastName (Last name)
Manager (Manager)
SPS-MasterAccountName (Master Account Name)
SPS-MemberOf (MemberOf)
CellPhone (Mobile phone)
SPS-MySiteUpgrade (My Site Upgrade)
PreferredName (Name)
SPS-ObjectExists (Object Exists)
Office (Office)
SPS-Location (Office Location)
OfficeGraphEnabled (OfficeGraphEnabled)
SPS-OWAUrl (Outlook Web Access URL)
SPS-PastProjects (Past projects)
SPS-Peers (Peers)
PersonalURL (Personal URL)
PersonalSpace (Personal site)
SPS-PhoneticDisplayName (Phonetic Display Name)
SPS-PhoneticFirstName (Phonetic First Name)
SPS-PhoneticLastName (Phonetic Last Name)
PictureURL (Picture)
PreferredDataLocation (PreferredDataLocation)
SPS-ProxyAddresses (Proxy addresses)
PublicSiteRedirect (Public site redirect)
PulseMRUPeople (PulseMRUPeople)
QuickLinks (Quick links)
SPS-ResourceAccountName (Resource Forest Account Name)
SPS-ResourceSID (Resource Forest SID)
SID (SID)
SPS-SipAddress (SIP Address)
SPS-AdjustHijriDays (SPS-AdjustHijriDays)
SPS-AltCalendarType (SPS-AltCalendarType)
SPS-CalendarType (SPS-CalendarType)
SPS-ContentLanguages (SPS-ContentLanguages)
SPS-Department (SPS-Department)
SPS-FeedIdentifier (SPS-FeedIdentifier)
SPS-FirstDayOfWeek (SPS-FirstDayOfWeek)
SPS-FirstWeekOfYear (SPS-FirstWeekOfYear)
SPS-HashTags (SPS-HashTags)
SPS-HideFromAddressLists (SPS-HideFromAddressLists)
SPS-Locale (SPS-Locale)
SPS-MUILanguages (SPS-MUILanguages)
SPS-MultiGeoFlags (SPS-MultiGeoFlags)
SPS-O15FirstRunExperience (SPS-O15FirstRunExperience)
SPS-PersonalSiteCapabilities (SPS-PersonalSiteCapabilities)
SPS-PersonalSiteFirstCreationError (SPS-PersonalSiteFirstCreationError)
SPS-PersonalSiteFirstCreationTime (SPS-PersonalSiteFirstCreationTime)
SPS-PersonalSiteInstantiationState (SPS-PersonalSiteInstantiationState)
SPS-PersonalSiteLastCreationTime (SPS-PersonalSiteLastCreationTime)
SPS-PersonalSiteNumberOfRetries (SPS-PersonalSiteNumberOfRetries)
SPS-PictureExchangeSyncState (SPS-PictureExchangeSyncState)
SPS-PicturePlaceholderState (SPS-PicturePlaceholderState)
SPS-PictureTimestamp (SPS-PictureTimestamp)
SPS-PointPublishingUrl (SPS-PointPublishingUrl)
SPS-PrivacyActivity (SPS-PrivacyActivity)
SPS-PrivacyPeople (SPS-PrivacyPeople)
SPS-RecipientTypeDetails (SPS-RecipientTypeDetails)
SPS-RefreshToken (SPS-RefreshToken)
SPS-RegionalSettings-FollowWeb (SPS-RegionalSettings-FollowWeb)
SPS-RegionalSettings-Initialized (SPS-RegionalSettings-Initialized)
SPS-SharePointHomeExperienceState (SPS-SharePointHomeExperienceState)
SPS-ShowWeeks (SPS-ShowWeeks)
SPS-TenantInstanceId (SPS-TenantInstanceId)
SPS-Time24 (SPS-Time24)
SPS-UserPrincipalName (SPS-UserPrincipalName)
SPS-UserType (SPS-UserType)
SPS-WorkDayEndHour (SPS-WorkDayEndHour)
SPS-WorkDayStartHour (SPS-WorkDayStartHour)
SPS-WorkDays (SPS-WorkDays)
SPS-SavedAccountName (Saved Account Name)
SPS-SavedSID (Saved SID)
SPS-School (Schools)
SPS-Skills (Skills)
SPS-SourceObjectDN (Source Object Distinguished Name)
SPS-StatusNotes (Status Message)
SPS-TimeZone (Time Zone)
Title (Title)
UserName (User name)
WebSite (Web site)
WorkEmail (Work e-mail)
WorkPhone (Work phone)
msOnline-ObjectId (msOnline-ObjectId)
```

Comment: You would need to remove their license/exclude them from AAD Connect replication/delete the account.

Comment: @TrevorSeward in our case,  we do not delete any leaver account, we block them as shown in the picture i provided.. i think our admin do this, so if the user return back, we can just enable his account + his onedrive files will not get removed.. so not sure if inside the SP user profile service we can distinguish those blocked users?

Comment: Likely it is feeding from Azure AD. You need to delete the user.

Comment: @TrevorSeward the app we are using will not have direct connection to Azure AD, it reads its data from SP user profile service,, and we do not delete leaver users , we only block them.. as mentioned before.. so can i know the blocked users from the SP user profile service?

Comment: When they're no longer in AAD or delicensed.

Comment: @TrevorSeward thanks for the reply .. what does AAD stand for? and how i can know from the SP user profile that the user is de-licensed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the software vendor and request that they add some other method to distinguish an active or deactive user. Users are kept in the UPSA as long as they are licensed/are present in Azure AD.

If you cannot do either, then you need to look at on-prem SharePoint where you have more control over the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. now moving to on-prem is not an option for us. and the app provides a list of properties which we can use to filter users, i am already using the `SPS-HideFromAddressLists` property as shown above which worked for some leavers. i edited the question with the full list of these properties. you advice will be highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: You need to talk to the app vendor if their filtering is not working for you, then.